# How to upload multiple images as an array in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

I want to make a puzzle.To make the puzzle, I want to upload 4 images with other input fields through an array from admin panel.

My json looks like this:

```
"qImage": "https://i.ibb.co/9gKCrT0/16-september-q1-1.png",
    "qText": "",
    "qDifficultyLevel":1,
    "qOptions": [{
        "option": "https://i.ibb.co/s5N4Szh/19.png",
        "isAnswer": false
    }, {
        "option": "https://i.ibb.co/CKKS7r2/29.png",
        "isAnswer": true
    }, {
        "option": "https://i.ibb.co/XJpQRNm/35.png",
        "isAnswer": false
    }, {
        "option": "https://i.ibb.co/QD6ypMM/54.png",
        "isAnswer": false
    }],
    "qAnswer":1,
```

Here **qImage** is the photo of the question. Here in **qOptions** array, the **option** variable contains the images of answers and with each image, I want to set the value of **isAnswer** a boolean value **true/false**.

How to do this ? Please help.

**My code:**

```
<form @submit.prevent="">
      <md-card>
        <md-card-header>
          <h4 class="title">Add a new Puzzle</h4>
        </md-card-header>

        <md-card-content>
          <div class="md-layout">
            <!-- <div class="md-layout-item md-small-size-100 md-size-75">
              <md-field>
                <label>Puzzle Title</label>
                <md-input v-model="title"></md-input>
              </md-field>
            </div> -->

            <div class="md-layout-item md-small-size-100 md-size-75">
              <label>Puzzle Image</label><br />
              <input
                class="form-control"
                type="file"
                ref="qImage"
                v-on:change="puzzleImage"
              />
            </div>
            <br /><br />

            <div class="md-layout-item md-small-size-100 md-size-75">
              <md-field>
                <label>Question Text</label>
                <md-input v-model="qText"></md-input>
              </md-field>
            </div>

            <div class="md-layout-item md-small-size-100 md-size-75">
              <md-field>
                <label>Puzzle Difficulty Level</label>
                <md-input v-model="qDifficultyLevel"></md-input>
              </md-field>
            </div>

            <div class="md-layout-item md-small-size-100 md-size-75">
              <md-field>
                <label>Puzzle Title</label>
                <md-input v-model="title"></md-input>
              </md-field>
            </div>
<div class="md-layout-item md-small-size-100 md-size-75">
              <label>Puzzle Answers</label><br />
              <input
                class="form-control"
                type="file"
                ref="qOptions.option"
                v-on:change="puzzleImage"
              />
            </div>

            <div class="md-layout-item md-size-100 text-right">
              <md-button class="md-raised md-success" type="submit"
                >Add Puzzle</md-button
              >
            </div>
          </div>
        </md-card-content>
      </md-card>
    </form>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      formData: {
        qImage: "",
        qText: "",
        qDifficultyLevel: "",
      },
```

These are the codes I have done so far.
How to modify the code of **puzzle answers** field to upload those images through an array with **isAnswer: true/false**?